# FAB & Textview as ListViewItem

Tags: android

I had a listview which item contain fab & textview. The listviewitem layout code bellow :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabActiveStat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fabActiveStat"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fabActiveStat"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fabEdit"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fabEdit"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Adapter Code Below :

```
ctx = getActivity();
    // The desired columns to be bound
    AScolumns = new String[]{
            //dbHandler.COLUMN_ID,
            dbHandler.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
            //dbHandler.COLUMN_ACTIVE_STATUS
    };

    AIto = new int[]{
            //R.id.fabActiveStat,
            R.id.tvDesc,
            //R.id.fabEdit
    };

    dbHandler = new databaseHandler(ctx, null, null, 1);
    csAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ctx, R.layout.view_categ_data, null, AScolumns, AIto, 0);
    lvCategory.setAdapter(csAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    lvCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Listview di click");
        }
    });
}
```

When all fab removed and I'm using more than one textview listview on item click work just fine. But when the fab used listview on item click didn't work at all. Based on what I read on the internet focusable must be set to false, but that didn't work to. Anyone know how to put fab as list view item and make the textview & fab clickable?

Note : I am a novice

Comment: can you post the listview adapter code ?

Comment: I already edit my question and add it. Currently I'm just using simplecursoradapter. But I plan to create custom adapter once this problem solved.

Comment: I think I must using custom simple cursor adapter. Got any link related to cursorloader and custom simple cursor adapter?

Comment: Have you search something about `RecyclerView` ? you can google it first, and check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RecyclerView`. I use the String model here, but you can use your own custom model later. To populate a list (of items), you need to create custom adapter and custom view (just like you did). Here is the custom adapter:

```
public abstract class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<String> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false); //use your custom view here
    return new BodyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String model = data.get(position);
    BodyViewHolder body = (BodyViewHolder) holder;
    body.populate(model);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class BodyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvDesc;
    FloatingActionButton btn_edit;
    FloatingActionButton btn_active;
    ImageView imageView;

    public BodyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        btn_active = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id. fabActiveStat);
        btn_edit = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fabEdit);
    }

    public void populate(final String model) {
        tvDesc.setText(model);

        btn_edit.setOnClickListener(view -> onModelClick(model));//firing listener to btn_edit, call the abstract method
    }
}

public abstract void onModelClick(ProductModel model);

}
```

In your xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your activity:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

List<String> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter adapterProduct = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listProduct) {
    @Override
    public void onModelClick(String model) {
        //your custom action
    }
};

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterProduct);

//add some data to the ArrayList

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I hadn't tested it yet. I had to update my entire code to support recyclerview, databinding. But from what I read from the net yours answer should be correct. Thank's @jemsnaban